# Sum Two or More Tables Element-wise in MS Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I got a problem. I have some tables in MS Excel, and I want to sum them element-wise and the result should be of the same shape.

These are the original tables:

Table 1:

```
12 | 02 | 01 | 09
01 | 10 | 21 | 39
06 | 13 | 04 | 07
```

Table 2:

```
08 | 13 | 02 | 09
02 | 11 | 15 | 14
06 | 02 | 06 | 06
```

The desired result is:
Table 3:

```
20 | 15 | 03 | 18
03 | 21 | 36 | 53
12 | 15 | 10 | 13
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sum the two cells in the upper left hand corner and then copy the formula over the required range? What difficulty are you running into? It seems extremely straight-forward.

Comment: You're right, but I'm looking for something more flexible, so if I add more tables I don't need to do it all again. Because in reality there are a lot of big tables.

Comment: Two options as I see. 1. Don't know if this is a good option, but excel have a function called "[consolidate](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/consolidate.html)", which is made to consolidate ranges/data. 2. A better option is to use power pivot. Use tables and then link everything to a data model "Add this data to the Data Model". Then you can combine the data to a powerpivot table that can be refreshed and you can easily add more tables.